# Composer always download the fontend assets

Tags: yii2, composer-php

Every time I used composer installed extension to Yii2,it always download the frontend assets.Its so slow!How can I fix this?
[This is what Composer download,every time I install the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlRdV.jpg)

This is Composer.json
    `"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": [
        "yii2",
        "framework",
        "advanced",
        "project template"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
        "ijackua/yii2-lepture-markdown-editor-widget": "dev-master",
        "aliyuncs/oss-sdk-php": "^2.2",
        "yiichina/yii2-md-editor": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.phpcomposer.com"
        },
        "packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.laravel-china.org"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: How about sharing your `composer.json`?

Comment: i think is only checking, you can use `-vvv` in composer to check verbosity messages, maybe theres some clue in.

Comment: I post my composer.json & I had used -vvv.That picture is the -vvv details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue with fxp/composer-asset-plugin which Yii2 uses in order to download NPM as well as Bower assets. Each time a new library is added the plugin will enumerate all the versions of NPM as well as Bower assets required by the project hence downloading lots of data from Github. Official Yii2 developers are considering to move to a better alternative package manager for NPM as well as Bower like https://asset-packagist.org/ as discussed here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/13064